# SQLalchemy- How I can extract table from sqlite file?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to extract table information from sqlite file.
I could list all the table name following this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310549/list-database-tables-with-sqlalchemy) and tried to extract table information using query method on the session instance. But I got following error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: ComponentSizes [SQL: 'SELECT ComponentSizes']
```

Does anyone know how should I revise following code in order to extract table specifying the table name?

```
class read():
    def __init__(self,path):
        engine = create_engine("sqlite:///" + sqlFile)
        inspector=inspect(engine)
        for table_name in inspector.get_table_names():
            for column in inspector.get_columns(table_name):
                #print("Column: %s" % column['name'])
                print (table_name+" : "+column['name'])

        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self.session = Session()

    def getTable(self,name):
        table=self.session.query(name).all()
        return table


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test=read(sqlFile)
    test.getTable('ComponentSizes')
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is suggestive of what is going wrong. Your code is translating into SQL - `SELECT ComponentSizes` which is incomplete. It's not clear for what is your end goal. If you want to extract contents of a  table into CSV, you could do this:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

con = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
outfile = open('mydump.csv', 'wb')
outcsv = csv.writer(outfile)

cursor = con.execute('select * from ComponentSizes')

# dump column titles (optional)
outcsv.writerow(x[0] for x in cursor.description)
# dump rows
outcsv.writerows(cursor.fetchall())

outfile.close()
```

Else, if you want contents of the table into a pandas df for further analysis, you could choose to do this:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
# Create your connection.
cnx = sqlite3.connect('file.db')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM ComponentSizes", cnx)
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding!