No Output When Connecting MySQL with Python
No Output When Connecting MySQL with Python
I am trying to connect MySQL with Python. When I run my code, I see no output, even though I expect to see a list of databases. Here’s my code:
import mysql.connector

try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="mysql1234")
    
    if mydb.is_connected():
        print("Connection successful")
        
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
        
        results = mycursor.fetchall()  # Fetch data
        if results:
            for x in results:
                print(x)
        else:
            print("No databases found.")
    else:
        print("Connection failed.")

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(f"Error: {err}")
finally:
    if 'mydb' in locals() and mydb.is_connected():
        mycursor.close()
        mydb.close()

Issue:

I can connect to the server, but I don't see any databases listed. What might be wrong?

Environment:

Python version: 3.11
MySQL version:8.0.15
Operating System: Windows


Your code looks good, and with replacements to my database, I get results with your code copied. The only things I did, not covered by your description, were to launch the DB software, create a test database, add some data to it and close. But that should hardly be necessary. Add logs. It's probably something really minor.

Ah hey another thing could be the root user. I created another user and logged in using it in my code. Could there be surprising security settings against using as root?

Usually the root user can do anything. What happens if you do this using the regular CLI client?

There's no need for if mydb.is_connected(): If it can't connect an exception will be raised.

@MikaelM I tried creating a new user, but I'm still facing the same issue. Do you have any additional recommendations I could try?

@Barmar When I run the line 'SHOW DATABASES' using the regular CLI client, it works fine. However, I'm having trouble with it in Python. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

If you're using the same same database and credentials, I can't think of a good reason why the results are different.

Not really an answer, but you could try using a package like SQLAlchemy, which abstracts away much of the basic stuff, see also the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310549/list-database-tables-with-sqlalchemy

"Record" is a key word in Python referring to a tuple list... "x" doesn't appear to be defined.  So the For Loop should read:
For record in results:
Then retrieve the "values" for each record
